# Why did vue.config.js stop working on the server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

vuejs.config.js was working properly, but stopped today.

1) I tried deleting vuejs.config.js completely and 'vue-cli-service build' still builds the project using the old vuejs.config.js as if it has cached it.

2) I made mistakes in the config on purpose, 'vue-cli-service build' only notices gross syntax errors.

3) I created a new vue project on the same server, it doesn't read vue.config.js too.

**vue --version**

```
@vue/cli 4.3.1
```

**lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "inspect": "vue-cli-service inspect"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "scss-lint": "0.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vue-smooth-scrollbar": "^0.1.2",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-spritesmith": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "iconfont-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.js:**

```
const IconfontPlugin = require('iconfont-plugin-webpack')
const SpritesmithPlugin = require('webpack-spritesmith')

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        outputDir: "./public",
        entry: './src/main.js',
        plugins: [
            new IconfontPlugin({
                src: './src/iconfont/',
                family: 'gpiconfont',
                dest: {
                    font: './src/fonts/[family].[type]',
                    css: './src/styles/partials/gpiconfont.scss'
                },
                watch: {
                    pattern: './src/iconfont/*.svg',
                }
            }),
            new SpritesmithPlugin({
                src: {
                    cwd: './src/icons',
                    glob: '*.png'
                },
                target: {
                    image: './src/img/icons-sprite.png',
                    css: './src/css/icons-sprite.css'
                },
                apiOptions: {
                    cssImageRef: "./src/img/icons-sprite.png"
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: '@import "./src/styles/main.scss";'
            }
        },
        extract: true
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the `webpack-spritesmith` dependency

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that's not the point, i installed `webpack-spritesmith`, result is the same. Same goes for clean new projects.